# Hide all `numbers` except last 4 using js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm struggling to find the proper regex to replace my phone number string. The goal is to mask all `numbers` except the last 4.

I have `/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*"` but it won't work with other symbols such as `(` and `-`

For example

`'1234567890'.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");` -> `******7890` (works)

`'(123)456-7890'.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");` -> `(123)456-7890` (doesn't work, I want `(***)***-7890` here)

So I want to be able to ignore all symbols except numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```js
/\d(?=(?:\D*\d){4})/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/57Yqt6/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (4 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){4}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**See code example**:

```js
const strings = ["(123)456-7890", "1234567890"]
strings.forEach( phone_number =>
  console.log(phone_number.replace(/\d(?=(?:\D*\d){4})/g, "*"))
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp only matches a digit that's immediately followed by 4 more digits. But in the second example you have punctuation characters between the digits that should be replaced and the last 4 digits. You need to allow for that in the lookahead, by putting `.*` at the beginning to match anything in between.

```js
result = '1234567890'.replace(/\d(?=.*\d{4})/g, "*");
console.log(result);
result = '(123)456-7890'.replace(/\d(?=.*\d{4})/g, "*");
console.log(result);
```