# how to replace all in a given string except the last 4 digits like **** **** **** 4587

Tags: javascript, java

`"\\d(?=\\d{4})","*"`

I've tried it like that but it does not seem to be working it gives me the exact same string i entered to the scanner

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Two different languages.

Comment: is it answer to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66572966/hide-all-numbers-except-last-4-using-js-regex

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on a simple regex to get each group of numbers, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over that array to produce the desired result, [`joining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) it up into a new string at the end.

```js
const str = '1234 1234 1234 5678';
const re = /(\d+)/g;

const out = str
  .match(re)
  .map((el, i, arr) => {
    if (i < arr.length - 1) return '****';
    return el;
  })
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply slice the string and save its four-last characters and append it to the result string after your done with the replacement

```js
let str = '6135 4639 4990 1032'

function hideChars(str) {
    const stars = str.slice(0, str.length - 4).replace(/\d/g, "*")
    const fourLast = str.slice(str.length - 4, str.length)
    return stars + fourLast 
}
const result = hideChars(str)
// result = **** **** **** 1032
```